# extending an isomorphism of a field to an embedding

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic extension of $F$, contained in an algebraic closure $E$ of $F$. 
Let $\alpha \in K$, $m(x)$ be its minimal polynomial over $F$ and $\beta$ a root of $m(x)$ in $E$, then there is an isomorphism of $F(\alpha)$ on  $F(\beta)$ over $F$, mapping $\alpha $ on $\beta$. How to extend this isomorphism to an embedding of $K$ in $E$ ? I need some help, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a little Zorn's Lemma? Define

$$\mathcal U:=\left\{\;(L,\phi)\;,\;\;F(\alpha)\le L\le K\;,\;\;\phi:L\to E\;\;\text{is an embedding s.t.}\;\;\phi\restriction_{F(\alpha)}=f\;\right\}$$

where $\;f:F(\alpha)\to F(\beta)\;$ is the given isomorphism.

Note that $\;\mathcal U\neq\emptyset\;$ since for example $\;(F(\alpha),f)\in\mathcal U\;$, and we can partial order $\;\mathcal U\;$ by defining

$$(L_1,\phi_1)\prec(L_2,\phi_2)\iff\;L_1\le L_2\;\;\text{and}\;\;\phi_2\restriction_{L_1}=\phi_1$$

It's easy to check that any chain in $\;\mathcal U\;$ has an upper bound (why?), so that we have a maximal element $\;(M,\Phi)\in\mathcal U\;$ .

Finally, just check that $\;M=K$

Comment: It's easy to check that any chain in $\;\mathcal U\;$ has an upper bound, it suffices to take the union of the chain. so that we have a maximal element $\;(M,\Phi)\in\mathcal U\;$ .

but i do not know how to check that $\;M=K$,could you give me some help?

Comment: Clearly $\;M\subset K\;$ by definition. Suppose there exists $\;k\in K\setminus M\;$, so that $\;M(k)/M\;$ is a non-trivial extensions and there exists an embedding of $\;M(k)\;$ into $\;E\; $ (why? Observe that $\;M(k)/K\;$ is algebraic...) and there we can construct our contradiction.